# sql - what does '^\d+\D+$' mean in regexp

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

I came through an expression -

```
select * from table where regexp_like(field, '^\d+\D+$');
```

I'm sure of what the expression does, but please can someone explain what `'^\d+\D+$'` refers to exactly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

^ beginning of string

\d single digit

+ one or more occurrences of preceding

\D **non**digit character

+ one or more occurrences

$ end of string

So, it means one or more digits followed by one or more nondigits, and that should be the whole string, not a substring.